# MS GP eConnect create EFT Bank

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect

Simply trying to create via eConnect the EFT Bank informations on a customer. You go inside a customer - > address - > EFT Bank. I cannot find any informations in the eConnect documentation or on the web of the correct method to use. Trying my chance here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There no way except writing directly inside the database tables, this is for latest version : Dynamics GP v 10.